# COM Interface for Window Position

Tags: windows, com

I'm looking for a COM interface in Windows for repositioning a window. **It needs to be a COM interface because I am writing a proof of concept in mIRC script which has COM support**. I do not want to have to write native code to accomplish this

An example of what I was hoping for

```
 ComPtr<IWindowManager> x;
 x->SetHwnd(hwnd);
 x->SetPosition(0, 0)
```

Comment: Also if you're going to downvote the question, please kindly comment on how you would approach the problem then...

Comment: I seriously doubt there's a ready COM interface for that which means you can introduce a new interface for that and craft your own COM server and use that from your script.

Comment: That is true, but I that would require writing native code :) Which is my "Only if I must" option

Comment: Not much writing - most of your code will be boilerplate.

Comment: @sharptooth The goal was to write a com-in-mIRC article for a scripting wiki while also solving someone's problem of re-positioning the main window. The tutorial shouldn't have native code, so I'll have to think of another useful example